# Periods time schedule in DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView called TimesDgv has contain school periods times. I want automatically generate times. Like this Screenshot image. How can I do this?

This is my code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < TimesDgv.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = time.AddMinutes(40).ToString("hh:mm");
            }
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSwZf.jpg)

Comment: Could you explain your problem? You write about a screenshot but there isn't.

Comment: I update my post

Comment: What data is in the grid “BEFORE” you run the posted code? Does the grid have a data source?

Comment: No, it doesn't have data source. I have comboBox for start time for example I select from comboBox (8:00). When I click my button I want generate time in grid. If row is 'period' time will increase (40) minute and if 'rest' will increase (5) minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below that takes the initial starting time value from the combo box, then combines that to today’s date to create a `DateTime` object. Then a simple loop through the grids rows sets the time values based on the “periodName.” If the period name is “rest” then it adds 5 minutes to the date time and if the period name is not “rest”, then the code adds 40 minutes to the `DateTime.`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string dt = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + comboBox1.Text;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(dt, out DateTime currentTime)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < TimesDgv.RowCount; i++) {
      if (!TimesDgv.Rows[i].IsNewRow) {
        if (TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())) {
          TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = currentTime;
          if (TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "rest") {
            currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(5);
          }
          else {
            currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(40);
          }
          TimesDgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = currentTime;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid time in combo box");
  }
}
```